# Xamarin forms dynamic ContentPages

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I need some suggestions, help to solve any problems. I have to create a view with a dynamic count of ContentPages. I created two ViewModels, one with a logic and a stop watch and a second one to control the dynamic pages. It looks like this:

**CircleViewModel:**

```
public class CircleViewModel: ViewModelBase {
    public ObservableCollection<Circle> Circles { get; set; }

    private string _timeText;

    public string TimeText { 
        get => _timeText; 
        set {
            _timeText = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

   // Some ICommands and methods

   public async Task StartStopWatch() { ... }
}
```

**MultiPageViewModel:**

```
public class MultiPageViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    public ObservableCollection<CircleViewModel> Pages { get; set; }

    private CircleViewModel _currentPage;

    public CircleViewModel CurrentPage { 
        get => _currentPage; 
        set {
            _currentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    // Some ICommands and methods
}
```

**MultiPageView.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage ...
    BindingContext="{Binding MultiPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPage.Circles}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding CurrentPage.Title}"/>
        <Button Text="{Binding CurrentPage.TimeText}" Command="{Binding CurrentPage.StartWatchCommand}"/>

        <userControls:VerticalTabView ItemsSource="{Binding MultiPageViewModel.Pages, Source={StaticResoruce Locator}}"
    MoreButtonCommand="{Binding MultiPageViewModel.MoreButtonCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

VerticalTabView is a user control to change the current page.

I did'nt like the usability, so I changed the ContentPage to CarouselPage. With UWP it works fine, with Android the scrolling starts to stutter, in the output of Visual Studio appears "*The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.*" and crashes with an OutOfMemory Exception. The CarouselPage does not work with iOS currently.

How can I improve this? I am grateful for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have too much code in your content page's constructor?

Comment: I don't think so... What do you mean with much code in constructor? What is much ;-)

Comment: Have you broken down your code into methods or not? Or have you jam packed all of the code in the constructor!